# R Forecasting for highly seasonal revenue data

Tags: r, forecasting

I have three years of daily revenue data. There is some fairly constant data growth per year, but the data is highly seasonal with huge peaks in Q4 (black friday, before Christmass frenzy, etc) and intra-week seansonaly (high revenue on Monday, less and less during the week, lowest on saturday, starts to pick up on sundays)

Instead of using a boring spreadsheet with linear forecasting, I'd like an R script that takes for input three years worth of daily data and apply an algorithm to predict daily revenue forecast for the next 6 months. I'd love for the input to be just a CSV file with dates and revenue numbers.

I heard ARIMA is good, but an economist friend of mine who has seen my data thinks that forecasting with Kalman Filters would yield very good results.

Could someone post a script to show me how to apply either the ARIMA algo or the Kalman Filter algo to forecast my data?   Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It's also extremely specific to your situation and you're asking for someone to do your work for free.

Comment: I don't think anyone here can answer how to show the math on how a simple Kalman Filter can be done. If I knew the answer I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Exactly.  Math != programming.  Ask on a math forum or pay a tutor.

Answer (score 6):

While R certainly has tools that implement these analyses, they are power tools, and it would probably be best if you read up on them and how they work ... (Venables and Ripley's *Modern Applied Statistics in S* might be a reasonable starting point, although I don't know if it discusses Kalman filters).  In the meantime:

```
??arima
??kalman
?arima
?KalmanLike
```

Or, having installed the `sos` package:

```
library("sos")
findFn("arima forecast")
findFn("kalman forecast")
```

Or just Google "kalman filter R" (!!) -- I did and found that the first 8 (!) hits looked highly useful (the 9th was an introduction to Kalman filters in MATLAB :-) )

Others may feel differently, but I will generally spend more effort helping someone work their way through an analysis when I can see that they have tried tackling it for themselves ...

Answer (score 1):

This should be solved using Regression.  You would have 6 dummy variables for the day of the week impacts.  You would have 11 monthly dummy variables for the seasonality.  You would have dummy variables for each of the holidays.